# how to deploy jboss4.2.2.GA in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 10.5.2 with grails

Tags: grails, jboss, intellij-idea

I have a project which is running in jboss using grails.

What we are doing as of now is :

make changes in intelliJ, create war using grails command(at command prompt), run jboss at command prompt.

this is consuming somuch of development time.

Could anyone help in getting jboss configured in intelliJ(please note that I have IntelliJ community edition 10.5.2 )

please let me know whether its possible with community edition ?

--------------There is no provision of configuring application servers for intelliJ community editions ---------

Comment: hmmmmm not a valid question any more...as its community edition

Comment: Could you use Tomcat during your development cycle, and JBoss for QA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Ant or External Tools to automate this task, both are available in the Community Edition and you can either call Ant task before Run automatically or bind Ant task or External Tool to hotkey.

Comment: could you please explain it in detail how to use ant in this case.

Comment: may be i am not good at ant scripting, thats why I never opted for it

Comment: You can find details on IDEA Ant support in Help and for Ant reference use Ant site.